# My netbook keeps freezing

Tags: windows-7, freeze, netbook

I have a Dell Mini 1018 running Windows 7 which has been freezing around 1 to 5 times an hour at for about 60 seconds. The entire system will simply grind to a halt, not just the program I'm using, and whatever key presses or mouse clicks I make while it's frozen will only catch up when it's returned to normal.

I contacted Dell who had me run some diagnostics on the hardware, all of which checked out fine. They won't offer help beyond that without payment, saying it's a software issue not covered under warranty.

Which is why I turn to you, Super User. What can be done to rescue my computer from this chronic state of fail?

Comment: When it happens, have Task Manger opened to the processes tab, and sorted high-to-low. Post back what processes are taking up the bulk of the CPU power. As of now, it is hard to answer based on the info you gave.

Comment: I've had the task manager open in the past and there haven't been any CPU spikes. This doesn't resemble a CPU spike anyway -at least not any I've seen. This is a total system freeze. Absolutely nothing will rouse it. Not ctrl+alt+del, not anything.

Answer (score 1):

Does your netbook use SSD or Hard Drive?

I've seen issues with Intel's Matrix Storage or Intel's Rapid Storage where it could cause issues just like this. I had to remove the Intel program and the problem went away.

Comment: It has a regular old HDD. I installed a fresh copy of Windows when I got the computer and never installed either of those programs.